# excel vba I need to transpose data from columns to rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA solution to transform data from a scenario similar to the illustration below. From `Sheet1` copy first three cell values (A3,B3,C3) only if there is a value in any cell to the left of them (D3,E3,...) in `Sheet2`  past first 3 cell values (A2,B2,C2), and the first cell after that with a value (D3) and also copy the header value into the adjacent cell. Any additional values to the left get the same treatment and become the next row, again copying (A3,B3,C3). Then the next adjacent cell value (E3) along with the header value into the adjacent cell. Then move down to the next row in `Sheet1` where there are values after the first 3 cells until it has looped all the way through sheet1 to produce the example in `Sheet2`.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

I have searched for other similar solutions but cannot find anything that works. This is the closest I've found with minor edits on my part but doesn’t work, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim wsThat As Worksheet
Dim ThisAr As Variant
Dim ThatAr As Variant
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long

Set wsThis = Sheet1: Set wsThat = Sheet2

With wsThis
    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Find total value in D,E,F so that we can define output array
    Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("C2:G" & Lrow))

    '~~> Store the values from the range in an array
    ThisAr = .Range("A2:G" & Lrow).Value

    '~~> Define your new array
    ReDim ThatAr(1 To Col, 1 To 7)

    '~~> Loop through the array and store values in new array
    For i = LBound(ThisAr) To UBound(ThisAr)
        k = k + 1

        ThatAr(k, 1) = ThisAr(i, 1)
        ThatAr(k, 2) = ThisAr(i, 2)
        ThatAr(k, 3) = ThisAr(i, 3)

        '~~> Check for Color 1
        If ThisAr(i, 5) <> "" Then 'ThatAr(k, 4) = ThisAr(i, 4)
            k = k + 1
            ThatAr(k, 1) = ThisAr(i, 1)
            ThatAr(k, 2) = ThisAr(i, 2)
            ThatAr(k, 3) = ThisAr(i, 3)
            ThatAr(k, 4) = ThisAr(i, 4)
            ThatAr(k, 5) = ThisAr(i, 5)
        End If

        '~~> Check for Color 2
        If ThisAr(i, 7) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            ThatAr(k, 1) = ThisAr(i, 1)
            ThatAr(k, 2) = ThisAr(i, 2)
            ThatAr(k, 3) = ThisAr(i, 3)
            ThatAr(k, 6) = ThisAr(i, 6)
            ThatAr(k, 7) = ThisAr(i, 7)
        End If

        '~~> Check for Color 3
        'If ThisAr(i, 6) <> "" Then
            'k = k + 1
            'ThatAr(k, 1) = ThisAr(i, 1)
            'ThatAr(k, 2) = ThisAr(i, 2)
            'ThatAr(k, 3) = ThisAr(i, 3)
            'ThatAr(k, 4) = ThisAr(i, 6)
        'End If
    Next i
End With

'~~> Create headers in Sheet2
Sheet2.Range("A1:D1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1").Value

'~~> Output the array
wsThat.Range("A2").Resize(Col, 4).Value = ThatAr
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` or `Get & Transform` to merely unpivot the `ID# columns`.  It will produce what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variant array(dynamic array)  is simple and fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim c As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Set wsThis = Sheet1: Set wsThat = Sheet2

    vDB = wsThis.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    For i = 2 To r
        For j = 4 To c
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
                For k = 1 To 3
                    vR(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
                Next k
                vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
                vR(5, n) = vDB(1, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    With wsThat
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 3) = wsThis.Range("a1").Resize(1, 3).Value
        .Range("d1").Resize(1, 2) = Array("Value", "ID#")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! thank you for the assist. I am wondering rather then copying into column E can it just give me the middle section of the value where in

Comment: Please disregard the last comment.  This works great and does everyting I need it to do! thank you for the assist. One last thought, I am wondering rather than copying into column E of sheet2 the full ID# value in the header value from sheet1, can it just copy over the middle section of the value so that it displays 16 instead of 01-016-152, 17 instead of 01-017-10, 467 instead of 01-467-106 etc. in other words just grab and copy the value between "-" of the header and omitting any leading 0 where it applies.

Comment: @Lgar,  **instead  vR(5, n) = vDB(1, j)**   , use    vR(5, n) = Split(vDB(1, j), "-")(1).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not sure why I couldn't open your attached images.
But you might want to try this code:

```
Change this line:
wsThat.Range("A2").Resize(Col, 4).Value = ThatAr
To
wsThat.Range("A2").Resize(4, Col).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThatAr)
```

Hope this help