# How to stack up excel rows to column(s)? [as shown below]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a dataset with 50,000 records. The format is like shown below.

```
Category | A   | B   | C
---------|-----|-----|-----
X        | 100 | 120 | 150
Y        | 200 | 220 | 250
Z        | 300 | 320 | 350
```

I want the resulting table to look like the one shown below.

```
Category | Type | price
---------|------|-----
X        | A    | 100 
X        | B    | 120
X        | C    | 150
---------|------|----
Y        | A    | 200 
Y        | B    | 220
Y        | C    | 250
---------|------|----
Z        | A    | 300 
Z        | B    | 320
Z        | C    | 350
```

How can I do this in MS Excel?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137592/excel-vba-i-need-to-transpose-data-from-columns-to-rows/46138010#46138010)

Comment: Use `Power Query` (excel 2010-13) or `Get & Transform` (Excel 2016) to unpivot the `A B C` columns.

Comment: I got a way to do this just using formulas without VBA if that is the way you want.  But you will need to convince chris neilsen so I can add to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help you ;)

```
        Public Type res
            cat As String
            mtype As String
            price As Long
        End Type
        Sub arranger()
        'defs+inits
            Set src = Sheets("src")
            Set res = Sheets("result")
            Dim mydatas() As res
            lastrow = src.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            'just for safe :)
            If lastrow > 65000 Then Exit Sub
            ReDim mydatas(2 To lastrow * 3)
            act = 2

        'fill array
            For actrow = 2 To lastrow
                For col = 2 To 4
                    mydatas(act).cat = src.Cells(actrow, 1)
                    mydatas(act).mtype = src.Cells(1, col)
                    mydatas(act).price = src.Cells(actrow, col)
                    act = act + 1
                Next col
            Next actrow
        'write back in new format
            'headers
            res.Cells(1, 1) = "Cat"
            res.Cells(1, 2) = "Type"
            res.Cells(1, 3) = "price"
            'datas
            For act = 2 To UBound(mydatas) - 2
                res.Cells(act, 1) = mydatas(act).cat
                res.Cells(act, 2) = mydatas(act).mtype
                res.Cells(act, 3) = mydatas(act).price
            Next act

        End Sub
```